# Related Rates (Cones)

Tags: derivatives

The question reads:  A water tank has the shape of a cone with height $2 m$ and radius $\frac{2}{3}$ m. If water is pumped into the tank at a rate of $3 m^3/hr$ how fast is the water level rising at the instant when the tank begins to overflow?

### The question asks to use similar triangles (r is $\frac{1}{3}$ of h), and thus solves the answer to be dy/dt equals $\frac{27}{4}π$.

However, shouldn't it also be possible to solve this through the product rule. If $V = \frac{π}{3}(r^2)(y)\frac{dv}{dt}\frac{π}{3}[2ry(\frac{dr}{dt}+ r^2\frac{dy}{dt}$.

However, plugging in 3 for $dv/dt$ and $\frac{27}{4}π$ for $dy/dt$, which should mean that $dr/dt$ equals a third of that or $\frac{9}{4}π$, the numbers don't equal. Why does it not work with the product rule?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are considering $r$ as variable. Which isnt the case here its constant . So $V=\frac{1}{3}πr^2h$ thus $\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{π}{3}r^2\frac{dy}{dt}=3$ . So $dy/dt=\frac{81}{4π}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the last answer is correct. And i would like to say sth else about the "r" which is basically a constant, and why is it a constant?

-When the conical tank has been filled, of course when it is filled, its radius is not affected, but only the height of it is affected by water building up!. That's why when you write your time-derivative equation; you derive and when comes to dr/dt you cancel its term out. And the rest, as mentioned by the first comment, is only the dh/dt which is the rate of change of length that you are required to get.

I hope i make it much clearer.